# CSS/jQuery selector to find elements which don't have a certain parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I found solutions to check if the parent does not have a certain class using `:parent`, but I want to have a node type excluded. In my case I only wants forms which are not placed withing an `article`.

I found a solution with filter, but I was wondering if there is a selector only way to achieve the same:

```
$('form.frm').filter(function() {
    return $(this).parent().is(":not(article)");
});
```

EDIT: This solution isn't perfect as it only works if the `form.frm` is an immediate child of article. Sometimes I have a div in between.
Here a simplified DOM structure:

```
<div id="pageContent">
    <articel>
        <div class="box">
            <form class="frm"></form>
        </div>
    </article>
    <articel>
        <form class="frm"></form>
    </article>
</div>
```

Comment: Whats the parent of article element? Would be great if you can share relevant DOM

Comment: You can produce a list of all elements that are not a child of an article. `querySelectorAll(':not(article)>*')` but you really mean a list of all elements that are not a ___descendant___ of an article, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is a modification of [Mohammad's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53433172/351785). The difference is that this code is not using `filter`, it is using `not`:

```
$('form.frm').not('article form.frm')
```

This is more or less the same thing. You specify a global selector, then exclude the `forms` you do not want (in this case, any `form` that is a descendent of `article`).

```js
$('form.frm').not('article form.frm').css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pageContent">
  <article>
    <div class="box">
      <form class="frm">article > div</form>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <form class="frm">article</form>
  </article>
  <div class="box">
    <form class="frm">div</form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, now the question, which solution is faster. Using the .not function or the filter with the .closest. I would assume the former...

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find any `article` parent of element and check if length of selector is `0`.

```
$('form.frm').filter(function() {
  return $(this).closest('article').length == 0;
}).css('color', 'red');
```

```js
$('form.frm').filter(function() {
  return $(this).closest('article').length == 0;
}).css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pageContent">
  <article>
    <div class="box">
      <form class="frm">article > div</form>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <form class="frm">article</form>
  </article>
  <div class="box">
    <form class="frm">div</form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also you can select all `.frm` and use [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to `exclude` all element has `article` parent.

```
$('.frm').not($('article').find('.frm')).css('color', 'red');
```

Comment: I just found this solution as well, but still wondering if there is a way to achieve this without filter